# Deportees to the Baragan Steppe, 1950s

Tags: 20th-century, romania, deportation-records

Is there a public record that lists the names of the people who were sent to [Baragan Steppe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C4%83r%C4%83gan_deportations)?

On June 17th, 1951, 9413 people from a security zone in Romania that bordered  Yugoslaviawere were deported to the Baragan Steppe. There was a secret list made up of anyone the Communist Romanians thought would be a threat if Tito were to attack.
It included: German Ethnic groups,  relatives of families who fled abroad, political appointmants, large rich land owners,  Bessarabians, Macedonia Romanians, former members of the Waffen-SS and any other enemies of the Socialist order.

They had to make homes and villages from nothing. Each Village was given a Romanian name. They were released in 1955 when Romania joined the UN.

I am looking for the names of the families of Bumbacari.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Joyfultune. You have enumerated various information about this deportation, but cite no reference for the knowledge. Please help us build a great site by providing references for the various information you include in your question.

Comment: You wrote, "... the families of Bumbacari." Is Bumbacari one of the villages ("Each Village was given a Romainian name")?

Answer (score 7):

The report [SÂRBII DIN ROMÂNIA 
ÎN GOLGOTA BĂRĂGANULUI](http://www.banaterra.eu/romana/files/sarbii_din_romania_in_golgota_baraganului.pdf) (pdf, in Romanian) has some name lists, from page 107.  The names are sorted by ethnicity then by destination village, I think, so Bumbacari appears multiple times. Google translate gives the following VERY rough translation of the heading of that section:

> "They Suffered" 
>   During our field research we aimed to come up with as
>   complete a record displaced persons. Further publish tables on
>   localities displaced persons originating and municipalities who were
>   sit or stand. We note that we are only in Serbian settlement order
>   within counties existing settlements is in alphabetical order. In the
>   localities where families are placed in the Cyrillic alphabet and
>   families are trecuŃi all members deportaŃi in their natural order. For
>   the female shown in brackets and their current name. The right of
>   those who died in Bărăgan I put the (†) and the there are separate
>   trecuŃi born. Tables are numbered so that resulting number of families
>   (houses) and deported number of people. At the end of the chapter are
>   summary tables.